# Pandas | Copy Dataframe Values Based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame`, `X`, in the following format:

```
Value1   Value2   Value3   Month   Area

   1       1        3        0      1
   4       10       45       1      1
   ..      ..       ..       ..     .. 
   15      11       10       34     1
   10      21       12       35     1
   1       2        2        0      2
   3       4        4        1      2
   ..      ..       ..       ..     .. 
   27      39       21       34     2
   23      42       32       35     2
   ..      ..       ..       ..     ..
```

From the `DataFrame` `X`, I want to create a `DataFrame` `Y`, with the same columns except for `Month` and `Area`. The rows of `Y`, need to be relative to the `Area` column but have the column values for the row of `X+1`.

For example, the first row of `Y` will contain the value of the second row of `X`, if the area is 1.

```
Value1   Value2   Value3   (Index) (Area)   

   4       10       45        0     1
   ..      ..       ..       ..     .. 
   10      21       12       34     1
   3       4        4        35     2
   ..      ..       ..       ..     .. 
   23      42       32       69     2
   ..      ..       ..       ..     ..
```

Then, I need to remove the rows in `X`, which contains the last `Month` Value, for every `Area`.

The `DataFrame` `X` would then be converted into something like the following:

```
Value1   Value2   Value3   Month   Area

   1       1        3        0      1
   4       10       45       1      1
   ..      ..       ..       ..     .. 
   15      11       10       34     1
   1       2        2        0      2
   3       4        4        1      2
   ..      ..       ..       ..     .. 
   27      39       21       34     2
   ..      ..       ..       ..     ..
```

This is my code at the moment:

```
#Define a list of indexes of X to Drop
to_drop = list()
prev = None
y_index = 0
    
    
    #Iterate through X
    for index, row in x.iterrows():
        if not prev is None:
            
            #If the Area is the same as before
            if row['Area'] == prev :
                #Append to the Y dataframe and increase y's index
                y.loc[y_index] = row[y_columns]
                y_index+=1
            #We found a new index. We want to delete the previous one, which will have the last 
            #month value for the previous area
            else: to_drop.append(prev_index)
            
        prev_index= index
        prev = row['Area']
    
    print("Removing some rows...")
    x = x.drop(x.index[to_drop])
```

However, when I check the new `DataFrames`, they seem to be losing a lot of information, such as full `Areas` being wiped out.
Any idea for a better approach, and what I could be doing wrong?

Please note, this is an explicative example. The Dataset is made of several thousand `Area` values, with around `30` `Month` Values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try this:

```
df['Month'] = df['Month'].shift()
df = df.dropna(subset=['Month'], axis=0)
df[df.duplicated('Area', keep='last')]
```

### Older solution

Does `drop_duplicates` work for you?

```
df.drop_duplicates(['Area'], keep='first')
```

Output:

```
   Value1  Value2  Value3  Month  Area
0       1       1       3      0     1
2       1       2       2      0     2
```

And,

```
df.drop_duplicates(['Area'], keep='last')
```

Output:

```
   Value1  Value2  Value3  Month  Area
1       4      10      45      1     1
3       3       4       4      1     2
```

Update, drops the last records in each group:

```
df[df.duplicated('Area', keep='last')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a clarification. Unfortunately, `drop_duplicates` wouldn't work, as the logic requires to remove the last `Month` value for every `Area`. This is because the Dataset is comprised by several thousand `Areas`, and multiple `Months`.

Comment: You want to remove the last row in each group with the groups defined by area right?

Comment: @user14802806 Does `df[df.duplicated('Area', keep='last')` work?

Comment: No, because that seems to only delete the last row by `Area`. I think what I want to do is closer to shifting all values by -1, according to the `Area` group, and then deleting the last row which should then be NaN. Then, I would have to do to `X` what you proposed. However that would be the last step.

Comment: @user14802806 Updated?

Comment: I guess I just found my solutions thanks to your answer!
```y = x.groupby('Area')[y_columns].shift(-1)
    y.dropna()
    x =x[x.duplicated('Area', keep='last')]

```